# Can you swap 2 harddrives in one computer back and forth?

Tags: mac, multi-boot, operating-systems, desktop-computer

I wanted to develop for mac, but the thing is that i dont have a mac. I was wondering if i could just buy another hdd, and then download the mac os so i dont have to dual boot, which i heard slowed down my system. Would there be any complications after getting the mac ios on the hdd, and would this even work? I would want to be able to switch back and forth between them by plugging one into my computer at a time.

Comment: Sata cables, and presumably ports actually have a rated lifespan by insertations IIRC. Notwithstanding the current stance on hackintosh questions (that they arn't really allowed here) this question seems to be inspired by unfounded conjecture - that dualbooting slowed down your systen

Comment: Aside from the question being off-topic, how practical would it be to try to develop software for a platform you don't own?

Answer (score 2):

Not only would this be incredibly clumsy, it would also be against Apple's licensing agreement for OSX.

If you want to develop Apple software, purchase Apple hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
No, You can not do that.

Long answer:
You can not install OSX on a PC. The reason is, that Apple creates drivers only for computers sold by them.
Note that it is not impossible to install OSX on a PC but You need to have lots of patients and effort to put in it to succeed. Just google 'Hackintosh' and You will find all the information You need. There is even a way to dual boot Windows and OSX.

Also it is not a wise choice to swap HDDs. You should stick to dual boot instead, it does not slow down your system.